# Jersey фильтр преобразования в utf8

Tags: java, servlet, rest, filter, jersey

Как преобразовать входящие entity в UTF8 используя фильтры Jersey? Пробовал использовать простой фильтр сервлета, но что-то пошло не так, да и хотелось бы разобраться с джерси.
Фильтр авторизации добавлял так:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
        <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.LoggingFilter;filter.AuthFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

А как добавить несколько фильтров в web.xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала предлагаю не принимать от клиента другие кодировки кроме utf-8

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
```

Comment: Но ведь приём это @Consumes?

Comment: Решено добавлением characterEncoding=UTF-8 в строку подключения к БД